# MySQL error #1690 (BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range) for UNIX_TIMESTAMP()

Tags: mysql

i get error `#1690 - BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range` for this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `user`
WHERE ROUND( ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - `expire` ) / 86400 ) = 7
```

i read about this error in Stackoverflow and see some notes about `cast` but i can't apply them to this query.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Checking if date in table is one week before current date ?

Comment: i want to find records that expire 7 days later.

Comment: @Drew yes, here you are: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78830/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second value in table will give negative result, so you get an error.

To make negative results possible in your case, use before query

```
SET sql_mode = 'NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION';
```

Answer (score 1):

### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `expire` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test`
--
truncate table user;
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `expire`) VALUES
(1, 1234567890),
(2, 1923456780),
(3, 1449397282),
(4,1449397282+3600);    -- note this is based on this moment I am writing this about a day ahead
```

### Query

```
select id,expire,seconds from
(   select id,expire,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(from_unixtime(expire), now())) as seconds 
    from user
) xDerived
where seconds>0 and seconds<604800; -- # of seconds in a week
+----+------------+---------+
| id | expire     | seconds |
+----+------------+---------+
|  4 | 1449400882 |    2870 |
+----+------------+---------+
```

So things that have not expired yet, but will within 1 week